# Jquery - how to make sure number doesn't go lower than zero

Tags: jquery

I have 1 button to lower the number, 1 button to inc it, and 1 input to display current value in input field.

look some thing like this

```
[-] 1 [+]
```

How can I make sure number doesn't go below 0?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.btn-minuse').on('click', function () {
            $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val()) - 1)
        });

        $('.btn-pluss').on('click', function () {
            $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val()) + 1)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿What have you tried? ¿Did you tried setting the attribute `min` on the html input tag?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you can just use `<input type="number" step="1" min="0">` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to check if the value is greater than zero before subtracting -1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var val = 0;
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.btn-minuse').on('click', function () {
        val = parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val());            
        if(val > 0){
          $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(val - 1));
         }
        });


        $('.btn-pluss').on('click', function () {
          $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val()) + 1)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code should be: `val > 0`, otherwise `val` can be `-1`

Comment: sure, I realized when send the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.btn-minuse').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(Math.max(0, parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val()) - 1))
    });

    $('.btn-pluss').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val()) + 1)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a variable to get the value in the input

```
$('.btn-minuse').on('click', function () {
          var inputValue = parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val());
          if(inputValue>0){
            $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(inputValue - 1);
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments the use of input type number and its functionality is quite simple, and allows you to set you minimum value and other characteristics.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

html:

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="1">
<button class="btn-pluss">+</button>
<button class="btn-minuse">-</button>
```

js:

```
let input = $('input').get(0); // conversion from jquery to regular element

$('.btn-pluss').on('click', function(){
  input.stepUp();
});

$('.btn-minuse').on('click', function(){
  input.stepDown();
});
```